# compare a "unknown" value with a int

Tags: java, max

Is it possible to compare an unknown data type to an `int`. I am trying to write a function that gets the max of nodes, but the data type is E not an `int`.

My code so far is..

```
public E getMax() {
  if (isEmpty()) {
    throw new NoSuchElementException(" error " ) ; 
  } else {
    Node n = first;

    E x ; 
    int max = 0 ; 
    while (n!=null) {
      if (n.data  > x) {
        max = n.data;
      }
    }
    return x;
  }
}
```

Comment: Just have `E extends Comparable<E>` and then use `x.compareTo(...)` to find the max.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would probably do something like this (I'm assuming that n.data is of type E).

For the generic, I would have:

```
class YourClass<E extends Comparable<? super E>>
```

and then your `getMax` method would look something like:

```
public E getMax()
{
    if (isEmpty())
        throw new NoSuchElementException(" error " );

    Node n = first;

    E max = n.data;

    while (n != null)
    {
        if (n.data.compareTo(max) > 0) // if n.data > max
            max = n.data;

        n = n.next; // move to the next node
    }

    return max;
}
```

Comment: +1. You may want to change `max = n` to `max = n.data` (two locations), and `Comparable<E>` to `Comparable<? super E>`.

Comment: @Lonenebula Good eyes, should be fixed. PS - if you didn't know, you can edit other peoples questions/answers!

Comment: what is the difference between the Comparable <E> to Comparable<? super E> ?